# Odds of Winning Office NCAA Pool

Tags: probability, problem-solving

I have 6 coworkers competition in a NCAA bracket. I'm trying to find out how to calculate who has the best chance of winning. For example currently the score card looks like:

Player 1. Current Right Picks: 14 Current Wrong Picks: 11

Player 2. Current Right Picks: 17 Current Wrong Picks: 7

Player 3. Current Right Picks: 16 Current Wrong Picks: 9

Player 4. Current Right Picks: 16 Current Wrong Picks: 7

Player 5. Current Right Picks: 13 Current Wrong Picks: 12

Player 6. Current Right Picks: 18 Current Wrong Picks: 5

Player 7. Current Right Picks: 14 Current Wrong Picks: 9

Now the reason they don't all add up to the same number is because some people picked a team to win in multiple rounds but they ended up losing in the first round which means they can't be right later on.

I know that each player's best possible score is 63 - current wrong picks.

Essentially I'm trying got get a formula that show each players chance of winning the entire bracket, i.e. have the highest possible score against the other players.

Thanks!

Comment: Is every pick equal value?  Total of 63 points available?

Comment: This question is impossible to answer because the probabilities are not independent.  If player 1 and player 2 made the same pick for a game, then they will either both win or both lose.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake above, it should be 63 - current wrong picks.

Comment: The question (as stated) is also impossible because the rest of the games are not coin flips; some teams are heavy favorites and others heavy underdogs.

Comment: But technically every team has a 50/50 chance of winning. If we assumed that can we do it?

Comment: @ChrisOlson: you are using "technically" wrong. "Technically" there's a reason why some teams are higher seeded than others. If one is willing to forgo reality than one can make a simplifying assumption that each game is decided by a coin flip. Even so the question is impossible to answer for the reason vadim gave: short of you showing all the picks to us the probabilities cannot be computed. (Unless you make the further simplifying assumption that the players are actually picking results for entirely independent tournaments, bringing us even farther from reality.)

Comment: I agree, but for the purpose of this experiment as as team gets further in the tournament they are competing at a higher caliber, would the hope of a tournament be that the championship game is two teams of equal weight, so every game draws you closer and closer to a 50/50 probably of each team winning?

Comment: I don't know anything about NCAA pools. How exactly is a winner selected?

Answer (score 0):

What if you just estimated a person's outcome with $$\text{Current Corrects}+\frac{\text{Remaining Undecided}}{2}$$

It's not great because if you pick a team to go all the way and it loses in the next round, it takes out a lot of your possible points, but off the top of my head, it is decent.

As far as probability of each perosn winning, you would need a distribution of possible outcomes for each person, which would get pretty hairy.